# Processing incoming e-mail data dynamically with scripting language -> database

Tags: email, unix, scripting, imap, solaris

I would like to process incoming e-mails (on IMAP account) as a e-mail fetching client and feed e-mail data into a scripting language to fill up a specific tables in database. The main goal is to process e-mail body text for data mining and metrics.

Best if run on common UNIX like systems: Linux, *BSD, Solaris

```
Infrastructure:

Mail Server <---using-IMAP--client<--- My Server--> Scripting lang. -> Database
```

What I found so far:

- MTA / [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) & [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/)
- [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) (python script)
- using [plain e-mail client](http://www.washington.edu/pine/) to grab emails to ~/.Mailbox and process them (expecting poor performance)

Any suggestions of what may be used to perform such task?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301213/how-to-efficiently-parse-emails-without-touching-attachments-using-python

Comment: I use fetchmail, procmail. .procmailrc then further process using php script. not the fastest solution, but easy to maintain and enhance IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Python, [imaplib](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) implements an IMAP4 client.

This and Nelson's answer should give you the template to follow:

1. Choose a scripting language that you want to use on your server.
2. Does it have an IMAP client library, extension, or built in functionality?
3. Does it have a connector to the specific database you want to use (MySQL, Postgres, MSSQL etc.)?
4. If answers to (2) or (3) are "No", go back to step 1.
5. ...
6. Profit!

Answer (score 2):

Having done this myself, I used Python and imaplib. Periodically poll the IMAP server to find and retrieve new mail. It's as "simple" as that. Simple is in quotes because you need to understand the IMAP protocol in order to use imaplib.

Alternatively, you can write a script that uses the [context.io](http://context.io) API. If you do that you may save yourself some pain in terms of learning the intricacies of IMAP.

If you have the ability to automatically forward email from the mail server to another address then you might consider forwarding your email to a service like SendGrid's Parse API or Mailgun, which process the email for you and make if available via API calls (that are generally easier to understand than IMAP).

As for the database, I found MongoDB *super* easy to setup connect to Python using the pymongo library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [**php-imap**](http://code.google.com/p/php-imap/) to connect to imap accounts from php, retrieve email, search messages, delete it, and of course saving it to database.